# Prove harmonic function inequality with the Mean-Value Property

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and let $u$ be a harmonic function
> in $\Omega.$ If $K \subset \Omega$ is compact, then prove
>
> $$ \sup\limits_{x \in K} |u(x)| \le \frac{n}{\omega_n ~dist(K,\partial \Omega)^n} \int\limits_\Omega |u(x)| ~dx. $$

**My attempt:**
Consider the following theorem

> **Theorem (Mean-Value Property):**
>
> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and let $u \in C^2(\Omega)$ be a harmonic function. If $\overline{B(x_0, r)} \subset \Omega$, then
> $$
> u(x_0) = \frac{1}{|B(x_0, r)|}\int_{B(x_0)}u(x)~dx.
> $$

There exists $x_0 \in \partial K$ such that $|u(x)| \leq |u(x_0)|$. At this early point, I'd like to use the mean-value theorem of a function, but I can't manage to prove one of its hypothesis, namely that $\overline{B(x_0, r)} \subset \Omega$.

Comment: Generally the set $\Omega$ is open +  connected in problems like these. Does that show up anywhere in your problem statement?

Comment: I edited $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ to $K \subset \Omega$, since otherwise the definition of $K$ does not make sense. Please check.

Comment: @rubikscube09 It doesn't. What was your idea considering that as a new hypothesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows directly from mean-value property of harmonic functions. We will assume that $\Omega$ is open.

Since $K \subset \Omega$ is compact and $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open then $r: = \mathrm{dist}(K ,\partial \Omega) > 0$ (notice that if $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$, then $r = \infty$, in which case we take $r$ as any positive number).

In view of the definition of $r$, for $x\in K$ we have $\overline{B(x,r - \varepsilon)} \subset \Omega$ for any fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough. In view of the mean value property for $u$ we have
$$
u(x) = \frac{n}{\omega_n (r - \varepsilon)^n} \int\limits_{B(x,r - \varepsilon)} u(y) dy,
$$
hence 
$$
|u(x)| \leq \frac{n}{\omega_n (r - \varepsilon)^n} \int\limits_{B(x,r - \varepsilon)} |u(y)| dy \leq \frac{n}{\omega_n (r - \varepsilon)^n} \int\limits_{ \Omega } |u(y)| dy.
$$
The right-hand side of the last inequality does not depend on $x$, and taking $\sup$ on the left-hand side over $x \in K$ we get
$$
\sup\limits_{x \in K} |u(x)|  \leq \frac{n}{\omega_n (r - \varepsilon)^n} \int\limits_{ \Omega } |u(y)| dy,
$$
for any $\varepsilon > 0$ small. Taking $\varepsilon \to 0$ produces the desired inequality.

Comment: The issue is that the mean-value property demands that $\overline{B(x, r)} \subset \Omega$.

Comment: @user71487, I've added a some details to the above argument. One can just use an $\varepsilon>0$ of room to ensure the closure of the ball lies inside $\Omega$.